# notes calendar button to set fields

Tags: button, calendar, lotus-notes

I am creating a toolbar button in Lotus Notes Calendar that fills in the calendar fields.  I cannot figure out how to put the checkmark in the field "Do not receive responses from invitees".  I can navigate to the field, but cannot get it to toggle to a checkmark.  Below is my script so far which sets several other fields and navigates to the toggle I want.

How can I get the checkmark after navigating to that field?  I tried to insert text, but it just wants to put the text in the text part of that field.

```
@Command([EditGotoField]; "Subject") ;
@Command([EditInsertText]; "subject info here");
@Command([EditGotoField]; "StartDate") ;
@Command([EditSelectAll]) ;
@Command([EditCut]) ;
@Command([EditInsertText]; "Thu 06/25/2015") ;
@Command([EditGotoField]; "StartTime");
@Command([EditSelectAll]) ;
@Command([EditCut]) ;
@Command([EditInsertText]; "10:00 am") ;
@Command([EditGotoField]; "EndDate") ;
@Command([EditSelectAll]) ;
@Command([EditCut]) ;
@Command([EditInsertText]; "Thu 06/25/2015") ;
@Command([EditGotoField]; "EndTime") ;
@Command([EditSelectAll]) ;
@Command([EditCut]) ;
@Command([EditInsertText]; "12:00 PM") ;
@Command([EditGotoField]; "EndTime") ;
@Command([EditNextField]) ;
@Command([EditNextField]) ;
@Command([EditInsertText]; @NewLine )  <-- right here is where I would execute a mouse click
@Command([EditGotoField]; "Body") ;
@Command([EditSelectAll]) ;
@Command([EditCut]) ;
@Command([FileImport]; "Microsoft RTF" ; "\\fillInBody.rtf");
@Command([EditGotoField]; "Subject")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@SetField("tmpSetBroadcast";"1")
```

will do it, and you don't need to navigate to the field first.

You can achieve most of what you are attempting by using @SetField instead.

Nick.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the SetField formula, Nick.  It is much easier.  However, I don't know the name of the ignore responses field, so I am still stuck on how to toggle that one.  I am assuming your example with tmpSetBroadcast isn't the name since it didn't work.  Is there a way to find the name of a field?

Comment: Actually, that is the name of the field - I have tried it and am able to toggle the checkbox. What version client and mailbox template are you using? Since you have added the @SetField code, could you please show me what your code looks like now?

Comment: Nick, I tried it again and was able to get it to work.  I think my problem was that I have to do all the @SetField commands last, or they don't seem to take. 
I am not sure what mailbox template I am using.  It is Notes 9.  If I could find the template, would it show me all the field names?

Comment: Updated code:
   vsubject := "subject in this line";
   date := "06/25/2015";
   starttim := "10:00 am";
   endtim := "12:00 pm";

   @Command([EditGotoField]; "Body") ;
   @Command([EditSelectAll]) ;
   @Command([EditCut]) ;
   @Command([FileImport]; "Microsoft RTF" ; "\\Calendar Body Button.rtf");
   @Command([EditGotoField] ; "Location");
   @Command([EditPrevField]);
   @SetField("Subject"; vugsubject );
   @SetField("StartDate"; date);
   @SetField("StartTime"; starttim);
   @SetField("EndDate"; date);
   @SetField("EndTime"; endtim);
   @SetField("tmpSetBroadcast";"1")

Comment: You need a bit of nous to find the fields - they're hidden on a subform within the Calendar Entry form. 

Is your problem now solved then?